# How do I force a system locale for a certain process?

Tags: winapi

I am writing a mod for an old video game which I don't have the source code for.

The game has critical bugs ('random' crashes, which are hard to debug without source code access) and from my observation, they only occur when using certain system locales - so far I've discovered it happens with the Japanese and Chinese locales. I assume said bugs happen due to misuse of some Windows APIs.

I inject my code to the app using DLL injection and I use Microsoft Detours.

My intention is to force the process to think that the system locale is English (US). My attempt was to inject the following piece of code in the main thread, but it didn't seem to work. I was able to notice that it didn't work as the game renders fonts differently according to your locale (monospaced font when using Japanese, for example).

This is the code I used to try reproducing the Japanese locale on the process:

```cpp
SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_JAPANESE, SUBLANG_JAPANESE_JAPAN), SORT_DEFAULT));
```

The call to `SetThreadLocale` returns 1, so I believe the call is successful (although its documentation is confusing - the return type is `BOOL` but the documentation says it should return `LCID`).

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: You could try to call [`setlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale) instead, after disabling per-thread locale status with [`_configthreadlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/configthreadlocale). If you don't have access to the CRT from your code you would need to find the implementation of either function and replicate that.

Comment: @IInspectable I can't find `setlocale` being used in the app.

Comment: BOOL success is `!= FALSE`. In this case, the previous LCID.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you couldn't set the locale of a process, you are only allowed to set it per thread.  `When a thread is created, it uses the user locale. The user locale can be modified for future processes and thread creation using the regional and language options portion of the Control Panel. The thread locale can also be changed using SetThreadLocale.`

Comment: @jea C requires that [`setlocale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) be process-global.